# Как сделать проверку на предмет в инвенторе

Tags: java, minecraft

Мне нужна проверка на предмет в инвенторе, тоесть если определённый предмет (например кровать bed) в инвенторе, то выполняется System.out.println("IS inventory!")

Answer (score 0):

Наверное что-то такое, только с блоком:

```
private boolean hasItems(EntityPlayer player) {

return (player.getCurrentEquippedItem() != null && player.getCurrentEquippedItem().getItem() instanceof net.minecraft.item.ItemBow);

    }
       if (hasItems(player) && (!player.worldObj.isRemote)) {
      player.addChatMessage((IChatComponent) new ChatComponentText((Object) EnumChatFormatting.RED + "Предмета нет в инвентаре "));
                } else {
      player.addChatMessage((IChatComponent) new ChatComponentText((Object) EnumChatFormatting.GREEN + "Предмет в инвентаре "));
                }
```

Comment: а как сделать для 1.12.2?

Comment: да это для 1.7.10, но для 1.12.2 вроде не менялось, моды давно не делал, вообще на фордже  или фабрик пишешь?

Comment: Нет, с 1.7.10 ооочень много поменялось, я на 1.12.2 forge

Comment: Да, но примерно что то такое же, сообщение в чат точно не менялось

Comment: да, но всё остальное поменялось

Comment: Пробовали вставить этот код?

Comment: да пробовал, не работает